# How to migrate from ~" in LESS 1.4.0

Tags: css, less

After upgrading to LESS 1.4.0 I get compile errors on the first line in the following code:

```
   (~"@{containerClass} .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index}") {
     // the resulting css
     left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
   }
```

Compile error: Unrecognized input

How should this code look in LESS 1.4.0?

I notice on http://lesscss.org/ that ~" is deprecated, but not how to use it for more than one element.

"Full" source for reference

```
// Caller
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements ("#fgScroller", @maxFeaturedGuides + 2, @seTotalWidth);

// will be called as long the index is above 0
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements (@containerSelector, @index, @seTotalWidth) when (@index > 0) {

  ~"@{containerSelector} .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index}" {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }
  ~"@{containerSelector} .scrollElement:nth-child(@{index})" {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }

  // next iteration
  .setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@containerSelector, @index - 1, @seTotalWidth);
}
```

Source code after applying changes suggested by @seven-phases-max

```
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements (~"#fgScroller", @maxFeaturedGuides + 2, @seTotalWidth);

// will be called as long the index is above 0
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements (@containerSelector, @index, @seTotalWidth) when (@index > 0) {

  @{containerSelector} .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index} {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }
  @{containerSelector} .scrollElement:nth-child(@{index}) {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }

  // next iteration
  .setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@containerSelector, @index - 1, @seTotalWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove parens and quotes:

```
@{containerClass} .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index} {
     left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
}
```

Update, here is the full snippet, copy and paste this to http://less2css.org/ to see the result:

```
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements(div, 3, 100px); // start the loop

// will be called as long the index is above 0
.setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@containerSelector, @index, @seTotalWidth) when (@index > 0) {

  @{containerSelector} .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index} {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }

  @{containerSelector} .scrollElement:nth-child(@{index}) {
    // the resulting css
    left: @index * @seTotalWidth - @seTotalWidth;
  }

  // next iteration
  .setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@containerSelector, @index - 1, @seTotalWidth);
}
```

Make sure --strict-math option is off (otherwise you need to add parens to all of the math expressions)

---

OK, and since my main interests sit somewhere in various LESS optimizations, here's a couple of hints (just in case):

```
#fgScroller {
    .setPositionLeftForScrollElements(3, 100px);
}

.setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@index, @width) when (@index > 0) {
    .setPositionLeftForScrollElements(@index - 1, @width);

    .scrollElement.nth-child-@{index},
    .scrollElement:nth-child(@{index}) {
        left: width * (@index - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I have added the entire code snippet to the original question.

Comment: Your fix together with this change in the caller did the trick:

`.setPositionLeftForScrollElements (~"#fgScroller", @maxFeaturedGuides + 2, @seTotalWidth);`